# Audio File continues to play even on leaving the view

Tags: iphone, ios4

What I am doing is

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(clickEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)clickEvent:(NSTimer *)aTimer{

 NSDate* finishDate = [NSDate date];

 if([finishDate timeIntervalSinceDate: self.startDate] > 11 && touched == NO){

  NSString *mp3Path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.mp3"];
  [self playMusicFile:mp3Path];
  NSLog(@"Timer from First Page");
  [aTimer invalidate];
  //[touchCheckTimer release];
  aTimer = nil;

 }

 else{


 }

-(void)playMusicFile:(NSString *)mp3Path{

 NSURL *mp3Url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mp3Path];
 NSError *err;
 AVAudioPlayer *audPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mp3Url error:&err];
 [self setAudioPlayer1:audPlayer];
 if(audioPlayer1)
  [audioPlayer1 play];

 [audPlayer release];

}
```

Now, on pushing another view this audio file keeps playing in the background.
Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is very common mistake

when you are leaving the view call stop method on the AVAudioPlayer variable pointer that you used to play the audio with

Comment: Well thanks @robin.I fixed the issue before you answered with the same